# How to echo script invocation without variable expansion of its args

Tags: bash, variables

From within a bash script, I'd like to echo script invocation **without** expanding variables passed as arguments.

Echoing script invocation **with** expanded variables can be achieved with

```
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]} ${*}"
```

Echoing (the script's, or any other comand's) history using

```
echo "$(tail -n 1 ~/.bash_history)"
```

shows script invocation without variable expansions, as desired, however not for the running script (only for scripts completed).

How to echo script invocation without variable expansion of its arguments from within the running script?

Comment: I fear it's not possible. The script itself only sees the expanded values, the calling shell knows the command line, but it doesn't forward it to the script.

Comment: Yes, and the $HISTFILE is only written when the shell exits, not when the script is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can execute your script with `bash -c script args`, what you want is doable with the `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` variable:

```sh
$ bash -c 'echo "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"'
echo "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"
```

This output is not easy to understand but you can see that the `echo` command, when executed, prints the unexpanded command. This is because the value of the `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING` variable is the literal: `echo "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING"`.

So, if your script is, for instance:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script="$0"
cmd="$1"
shift

echo "script name: $script"
echo "command line: $cmd"
echo "parameter: $1"
```

you can execute it as:

```sh
$ a=42 bash -c './foo.sh "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" "$a"'
script name: ./foo.sh
command line: ./foo.sh "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" "$a"
parameter: 42
```

Comment: What if the variable a is defined inside a file (vars.sh).
`source vars.sh bash -c './foo.sh "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" "$a"'`
does not work.

Comment: Just source in the bash command: `bash -c 'source vars.sh; ./foo.sh "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING" "$a"'`. Or export the variable before the `bash -c '...'`: `source vars.sh; export a; bash -c '...'`. Or directly write `export a=42` in `vars.sh` and then: `source vars.sh; bash -c '...'`.